# Nest , Fold ... is there an extension for more than 2 arguments?

Tags: functions

Fold is an extension of Nest for 2 arguments.  How does one extend this concept to multiple arguments.  Here is a trivial example:

```
FoldList[#1 (1 + #2) &, 1000, {.01, .02, .03}]
```

Say I want do something like:

```
FoldList[#1(1+#2)-#3&,1000,{.01,.02,.03},{100,200,300}]
```

where 100,200,300 are the values for #3. I know Fold doesn't work this way. I'm looking for an approach that will work like this...  ((1000*(1.01)-100)*1.02-200)*1.03-300).

Is there a way to extend Fold to more than 2 arguments? or is there a better approach for solving problems like this?

Comment: I have described exactly this problem [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node236.html), under the section "Restriction of Fold-ed function to two arguments is spurious".

Comment: Please, format your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there is. Group your extra arguments in a list, and address them by their positions in the function under `Fold`. For your particular example:

```
FoldList[#1 (1 + First@#2) - Last@#2 &, 1000, Transpose@{{.01, .02, .03}, {100, 200, 300}}]

(* {1000, 910., 728.2, 450.046} *)
```

Comment: Is there a way of extending this to one argument but TWO LISTS ?

Comment: @PraveenPIyengar Your question is not clear to me. You may want to ask a separate question on the site.

Answer (score 15):

To achieve the specific syntax you requested we can use something like this:

```
multiFoldList[f_, start_, args__List] :=
  FoldList[f @@ Prepend[#2, #] &, start, {args}\[Transpose]]
```

Example:

```
multiFoldList[#1 (1 + #2) - #3 &, 1000, {.01, .02, .03}, {100, 200, 300}]
```

> ```
> {1000, 910., 728.2, 450.046}
> ```

Here is another formulation which tests slightly faster and may be easier to read:

```
multiFoldList[f_, start_, args__List] :=
  Module[{ff},
    ff[x_, {y__}] := f[x, y];
    FoldList[ff, start, {args}\[Transpose]]
  ]
```