# How to use Fold with 3 variables

Tags: iterators

Suppose I define

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:=x+y+z
```

I wish to apply the Fold function to f along the lines of

```
Fold[f,1,2,Range[10]]
```

In other words, I want to fix x and y, while iterating over z. But this makes no sense as Fold will not accept more than 3 arguments. I realise that one solution to this is to redefine f as

```
f[{x_,y_},z_]:=x+y+z
```

Or something else along these lines, but I want to keep f as a function of 3 variables explicitly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the answer to your example supposed to be 85, as in `f[1, 2, #] & /@ Range[10] // Total`?

Comment: Exactly, but I need to do this for more general f also, not just linear.

Comment: Treat the constants as prepended elements on the base list, within the function index into them and the "rest" of the list as needed. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39476/nest-fold-is-there-an-extension-for-more-than-2-arguments)

Comment: @rasher In this case of two constants and one variable do the constants go into a List in the 2nd argument of Fold?

Comment: @bobthechemist: Depends on what user wants, but based on OP, yeah, two constants and first z in base list, rest of z in iterator list, function replaces last entry each iter...

Answer (score 3):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z

list = Range[10];

Fold[f[1, 2, #] &, 0, list]
```

> 30

This just adds 3 at each step as can be seen from FoldList

```
FoldList[f[1, 2, #] &, 0, list]
```

> {0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30}

```
Fold[f[1, 2, #] &, 0, list] ==
 FoldList[f[1, 2, #] &, 0, list][[-1]]
```

> True

Or perhaps you intend

```
Fold[f[1, 2, #] &, First[list], Rest[list]]
```

> 28

This still adds 3 at each step but has a different initial value.

```
FoldList[f[1, 2, #] &, First[list], Rest[list]]
```

> {1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an alternative:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + Plus @@ {y, z} // Total

f[Range@10, 1, 2]
```

> 85

```
f[Sin@Range@10, 1., 2.]
```

> 31.4112