# Continued fraction with different numerators

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

In Mathematica, is it possible to form the continued fraction of the following formula?
$$ f = a_1+\cfrac{b_1}{a_1+a_2+\cfrac{b_2}{a_2+a_3+\cfrac{b_3}{a_3+a_4+\cfrac{b_4}{a_4+...}}}} $$

Comment: You are looking for `Fold`?

Comment: @halirutan I read this post before, it's not what I need though.

Comment: Tony, please explain how your situation is different.  It looks similar on the surface.

Comment: Related: [(39476)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39476/121)

Comment: thanks @Mr.Wizard, let me check first, it does look similar~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it is really simple with `Fold`

```
Fold[a[#2] + b[#2]/(a[#2] + #1) &, 0, Reverse[Range[6]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For the updated question, I think you only have to modify this as `Fold[a[#2] + b[#2]/(a[#2] + #1) &, (Range[10]~Join~{0}) // Reverse]`, I put the 0 in there so it doesn't have a constant in the terminal fraction.

Comment: @JasonB That's what I want. Thanks :)