# Problem with FoldList: Use Foldlist with more than one List/Use FoldList with multidimensional array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following function:

```
vt[ea_, v0_, cm_, b_] := ea + (v0 - cm)*b
```

`ea` is a set of lists and `cm` is also set of lists, `b` is a constant and for `v0` the startvalue is 5000. After the first step the function should use the output of the expression  vt[ea_, v0_, cm_, b_] for v0. It is a recursion function. For this I can use the following FoldList definition:

```
FoldList[vt[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]], b] &, v0, {eacm}]
```

For `ea` and `cm`, I have a set of lists a little bit more than in the example below.

```
ea = {{5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 8, 9}} 
cm = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

Now I transposed this into a list of pairs with the following expression to use it in the FoldList command:

```
Transpose[{ea, cm}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

The output is the following multidimensional array:

```
eacm = 
  {{{5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{4, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}}}
```

But the `FoldList` expression above doesn´t work with this multidimensional array. It only works with one list. I think I have to change something in the `#2[[1]], #2[[2]]` arguments.

My first question is: what do I have to change in the `FoldList` expression above to get it to work? My second question is: can I transform the multidimensional array into a matrix or a set of lists with the form:

```
eacm = 
 {{5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{4, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}}
```

I think I am close to a solution of my problem. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: The second question is impossible, that's not a list. A list must always be enclosed by curly brackets. You can run `eacm[[i]]` for `{1,2,3}` to make three seperate lists

Comment: Ok thank you but that will be nearly immpossible because i will have like 10.000 set of lists or is there a fast way to automaticly get all the lists seperated? (I mean not to put in 1 and than 2 and so on?)

Comment: I think we're dealing with an XY problem here. Why not step back and discuss what your *actual* problem is first before we start discussing solutions?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [(39476)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39476/121)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vt[ea_, v0_, cm_, b_] := ea + (v0 - cm)*b

v0 = 3500;
b = 1.1;

ea = {{5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 8, 9}};
cm = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

The manner in which you created `eacm` is fine.

```
eacm = Transpose[{ea, cm}, {3, 1, 2}]

(* {{{5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}},
    {{4, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}}} *)
```

The change to the `FoldList` code is to wrap it in `Map` in order to apply it to the individual sub-lists in `eacm`.

```
Map[FoldList[vt[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]], b] &,
   v0, eacm[[#]]] &, Range[Length@eacm]]

{{500, 504, 508, 512}, {500, 497, 494, 491}, {500, 497, 497, 497}}
```

Mr. Wizard showed an improvement that directly uses `eacm` rather than `Range[Length@eacm]`.

```
Map[FoldList[vt[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]], b] &, v0, #] &, eacm]
```

or using a different syntax

```
FoldList[vt[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]], b] &, v0, #] & /@ eacm
```

Comment: Yes i already tried this but i want the FoldList command to stop after one List: {{5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}}, and her begin from new with the computation {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}},and here again {{4, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}} so i think i need somethin like this to hold the pair of lists in seperate lists:

Comment: eacm = 
{{5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{4, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}}

Comment: This is what i was searching for thank you very much Jack LaVigne

Comment: I have adjusted the description of the problem. I hope now it is a little bit easier to understand. Again thanks to Jack LaVigne for this great solution!!

Comment: Why would one not use `FoldList[vt[#2[[1]], #1, #2[[2]], b] &, v0, #] & /@ eacm`?

Comment: @Wizard They are identical

Comment: @Wizard Sorry, I mis-read it. I thought you were talking about the difference between using `Map[...` and `/@ eacm`. But you meant using `eacm[[#]]` and `Range` as opposed to simply using `eacm`. Your suggestion is better and I have incorporated it.

Comment: @Jack LaVigne, Many users with expert Mma proficiency use `expr[[1]]` and   `expr[[2]]` when `First@expr` and `Last@expr` will do the same thing. The code from you and Mr. Wizard is an example. The former takes a bit more time because Part has to evaluate the 1 or 2 to determine which part. Also, I find the later more readable (ie. easier for my eyes to parse). Hence I can't understand why we don't see more use of First & Last.

Comment: @Ted Ersek I agree.