# Applying FoldList using a Function

Tags: list-manipulation

Given

```
p={2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
```

I want to get the values which can be calculated by

```
 Table[(p[[i + 1]]*p[[i + 3]] - p[[i]]*p[[i + 2]]), {i, 5}]
```

resulting in

```
 {11, 34, 36, 96, 60}
```

I also can do it by

```
p4 = Partition[p, 4, 1];

f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := b*d - a*c

f[#, #2, #3, #4] & @@@ p4
```

What would be a concise way using `FoldList` without using `Partition` beforehand?

Comment: No need for `f[#, #2, #3, #4] & @@@ p4` , just `f@@@p4` do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***"... without using Partition"***:

```
BlockMap[f @@ # &, p, 4, 1]
```

> ```
> {11, 34, 36, 96, 60}
> ```

Comment: Wow! I never came across BlockMap. What would be a similiar solution as given in [120904] (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120904/problem-with-foldlist-use-foldlist-with-more-than-one-list-use-foldlist-with-mu) _italic_ **bold**

Answer (score 2):

```
p = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19};

f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := b*d - a*c
```

Three variants of `SequenceCases`

```
SequenceCases[p, {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> f[a, b, c, d], Overlaps -> True]
```

{11, 34, 36, 96, 60}

```
SequenceCases[p, x : {_, _, _, _} :> f @@ x, Overlaps -> True]
```

{11, 34, 36, 96, 60}

```
SequenceCases[p, x : {Repeated[_, {4}]} :> f @@ x, Overlaps -> True]
```

{11, 34, 36, 96, 60}

Answer (score 2):

```
p = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19};

f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := b*d - a*c
```

Using `MovingMap`:

```
Drop[MovingMap[f @@ # &, p, 3, 1], 3]

(*{11, 34, 36, 96, 60}*)
```